# Getting fridays data with in the year

Tags: soql

In my project there is a field called STUDENT,
and object is Joining Date.
So how i can access "who joining on Fridays in last year" by using Sales-force Object Query Language.

Comment: Are you sure that object is `Joining Date` and field `Student` but not vice verse?

Answer (score 2):

Sujith 
I assume that Student is your object and Joining date(column) is a field in Student object.

> Step 1: Create one formula field for student object which stores day.

```
CASE( MOD( Joining_Date__c - DATE(1900, 1, 7), 7), 0, "Sunday", 1, "Monday", 2, "Tuesday", 3, 
"Wednesday", 4, "Thursday", 5, "Friday", 6, "Saturday","Error")
```

> Step 2: Below is my SOQL

```
Student__c [] stu=  [select id from Student__c where Day__c ='Friday'  and CALENDAR_YEAR(Joining_Date__c) = 2014];
```

I think this might be usefull for you if i am wrong then correct me.

Answer (score 2):

In this way you also do

```
Student__c[] student=  [select id from Student__c where DAY_IN_WEEK(JoiningDate__c) = 6 and CALENDAR_YEAR(JoiningDate__c) = 2014];
```

1 for Sunday
7 for Saturday

i hope this useful for you.

Answer (score -1):

There is dedicated SOQL date function `DAY_IN_WEEK`

Check link below http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_date_functions.htm